# Getting two script tags for bundle with Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack

For some reason, I end up with two scripts in index.html outputted to my dist.  Not sure what part of my webpack script is doing this.

**index.html** (before webpack is run)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/css/ink.min.css">
    <script src="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/js/ink-all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/js/autoload.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9 ]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ink-ie.min.css" type="text/css">
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/css/master.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="/scripts/app.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html** (generated by webpack - notice there are now two scripts at the end for bundle. One with a hash, one without)

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>My Title</title><meta charset="utf-8"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/css/ink.min.css"><script src="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/js/ink-all.min.js"></script><script src="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/js/autoload.js"></script><!--[if lt IE 9 ]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ink-ie.min.css" type="text/css">
    <![endif]--><link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/css/master.css"/><link href="/lib/css/main.19f6cefd31f76cb95333.css?19f6cefd31f76cb95333" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><div id="app"></div><script src="/scripts/app.bundle.js"></script><script src="app.19f6cefd31f76cb95333.bundle.js?19f6cefd31f76cb95333"></script></body></html>
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const TerserJSPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const html = () => {
  return new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: './src/client/index.html',
    filename: './index.html',
    hash: true,
  });
};

const copyAllOtherDistFiles = () => {
  return new CopyPlugin({
    patterns: [
      { from: 'src/client/assets', to: 'assets' },
      { from: 'src/server.js', to: './' },
      { from: 'src/api.js', to: './' },
      { from: 'package.json', to: './' },
      {
        from: 'src/shared',
        to: './shared',
        globOptions: {
          ignore: ['**/*supressed.json'],
        },
      },
    ],
  });
};

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/client/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'app.[hash].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  devServer: {
    writeToDisk: true,
  },
  target: 'web',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserJSPlugin({}), new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})],
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        styles: {
          name: 'styles',
          test: /\.css$/,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          isProduction ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'less-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader', options: { injectType: 'linkTag' } },
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ['url-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: isProduction
    ? [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          filename: isProduction ? '/lib/css/main.[hash].css' : 'main.css',
        }),
        html(),
        copyAllOtherDistFiles(),
      ]
    : [new CleanWebpackPlugin(), html(), copyAllOtherDistFiles()],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

The reason you get two scripts at the end of your bundle because you added it once in your template file and once as your webpack entry file.

**In your template file**:

```html
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<!-- You should remove the next line -->
<script src="/scripts/app.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

**In your webpack config**:

```js
module.exports = {
  // Webpack will automatically import it in your HTML template.
  entry: './src/client/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'app.[hash].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
 ...
```

I recommend you to **remove the script tag in the template file** so you conserve the file hash.

#### Explanation

If we take look at the [repo](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) of the plugin, in the [usage](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#usage) section :

> The plugin will generate an HTML5 file for you that **includes all your webpack bundles** in the body using **script tags**. Just add the plugin to your webpack ...

Comment: How can you pair this up with webpack-dev-server? If you remove your manual src paths there will be nothing to reload... any suggestions? Thanks.